# Prefix Subversion comments in XCode?

Tags: xcode, svn, commit

Does anyone know if you can configure XCode to prefix the comment entry when attempting to commit files? I am using XCode 4.6.

The reason I ask is that I have multiple projects going on in parallel with multiple developers. I want a way to categorize the commit comments. Having a prefixed comment with the project name would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not in XCode 5.
It surprises me a bit that your teams use Xcode for committing anything at all, maybe managing commits with a third party solution would do the trick?